# ¿Es correcto usar «amarizar» o «amartizar» para aterrizar en Marte?

Tags: vocabulario, verbos, palabras-raras

En español, existe un verbo para describir la acción de aterrizar en la Luna: «alunizar».

Siguiendo esa misma idea, ¿se puede decir «amarizar» o «amartizar» para una nave que aterriza en Marte?

Comment: Esta pregunta me ha hecho echarle un ojete a lo que dice la RAE de *"amarizar"*: http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=amarizar  Una de las acepciones es *ovejas echando un huete* (más o menos)... Qué poco tecnológico queda eso... Pero me ha hecho gracia...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En su momento (2012) la respuesta de [Sergio Cinos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/2682/11102) era la correcta pero esto ha [cambiado](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amartizaje)

Tanto el sustantivo «Amartizaje», como el verbo «amartizar»​ se incluyen en la 23.ª edición del Diccionario de la lengua española (la Edición del Tricentenario), publicada en 2014.

https://dle.rae.es/?id=2GEXKcj

[image]

Por lo anterior «amarizar» es incorrecto pero «amartizar»​ es correcto para referirse a aterrizar en el planeta Marte.

---

<sub>Tocará esperar a las misiones a los otros planetas para tener Mercurizar, Venusizar, Jupertizar, Saturnizar, Uranizar, Neptunizar, y Plutonizar y tal vez exoplatentizar(¿?)</sub>

Comment: Hi @DGaleano - is there a specific reason you reverted the edit I did? I thought it was general SE policy to replace images of text with the text content (to improve searchability etc and so that [visually impaired](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/320235) users' reading software etc can read it) e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141752/how-to-handle-images-containing-text-vs-text

Comment: Thanks @ukemi for trying to make it better but I don't think it is a Spanish SE policy to replace images and a question in Meta does not make it a policy. I really don't see the need to change it to make it searchable. The reason I rolled it back is that I simply like it better as an image.

Answer (score 13):

No, no es correcto. Se ha pregungado a la RAE sobre [aterrizar vs. alunizar vs. amartizar](http://forodeespanol.com/Archive/AterrizarAlunizarAmartizar/jvwx/post.htm), y esta es la respuesta oficial:

> El verbo *amartizar* (formado sobre el sustantivo Marte a imitación de *aterrizar*) no está admitido por las Academias ni se recoge en el DRAE. Se trata de una creación innecesaria, puesto que *aterrizar* se define como ‘dicho de un avión o de un artefacto volador cualquiera: Posarse tras una maniobra de descenso, sobre tierra firme o sobre cualquier pista o superficie que sirva a tal fin’, y la expresión *tierra firme* equivale a ‘suelo’ o ‘superficie’ en general, y no a la del planeta Tierra en exclusiva. No obstante lo anterior, la RAE incorporó en su momento al Diccionario el término alunizar, ‘dicho de una nave espacial o de un tripulante de ella: Posarse en la superficie de la Luna’. Lo mismo podría decirse de su derivado nominal, *amartizaje*.

Es decir, el termino general es 'aterrizar' para todos los planetas o cuerpos celestes, menos el caso particular de la Luna, que tiene el verbo 'alunizar'