# ¿Se ha propuesto alguna palabra para los aterrizajes en otros cuerpos celestes además de la Tierra, la Luna y Marte?

Tags: verbos, solicitud-de-término, neologismos

- Desde 1925 se recoge en el DLE (y desde 1917 en otros diccionarios) la palabra *[**aterrizar**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=4E7cjdW)*.
- En 1970 el suplemento del diccionario de la Academia recogió *[**alunizar**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=29wS9mP)*.
- En 2014, y después de [mostrarse reticente](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/2682/12637), la RAE admite *[**amartizar**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=2GEXKcj)* en el diccionario. Ya incluso hasta [lo propone en Twitter](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/1156490972550893568).

Nuestro compañero DGaleano propuso algunas opciones en [su respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/27968/12637) a otra pregunta. Sin embargo, ¿se han usado en alguna publicación seria otros términos, ya sea en la literatura de ficción como en no ficción o prensa o lo que sea, que denominen a la acción de posarse una nave sobre otros cuerpos celestes?

Answer (score 13):

Si consideramos que "aterrizar" es la acción de tocar "tierra" (no necesariamente "la Tierra"), ese verbo puede aplicarse a la acción de posarse sobre cualquier planeta, a menos que su superficie sea gaseosa o líquida.

En [el libro *Formación de palabras y enseñanza del español LE/L2* de David Serrano-Dolader](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=P7JjDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT482&lpg=PT482&dq=amercurizar&source=bl&ots=-igk2FFNXE&sig=ACfU3U2NR2rcqEO_6uF18mVOY64Hoi44Sw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj3u7Htn9_jAhUVI7kGHW-3AsMQ6AEwEnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=amercurizar&f=false) leemos:

[image]

Comment: Y así se hace normalmente, sin recurrir a artificios que en nada enriquecen. Si se posa en tierra firme, atterriza, si lo hace sobre un liquido, ameriza.

Answer (score 3):

Todo este embrollo parte de la confusión entre *tierra*<sup>3</sup> ("material desmenuzable de que principalmente se compone el suelo natural") y *Tierra*<sup>1</sup> ("planeta que habitamos"). Como puede verse por la letra inicial, el primero es nombre común y el segundo propio.

Para acabar de liarla parda, existe un *tierra*<sup>2</sup> ("superficie del planeta Tierra, especialmente la que no está ocupada por el mar").

*Aterrizar* fue un neologismo construido a partir de *aterrizaje*, que es un calco del francés *atterrissage*. Como el primero que aterrizó lo hizo sobre la *tierra*<sup>3</sup> de la *Tierra*<sup>1</sup>, cuando empezaron a posarse aparatos sobre la Luna, alguien se quiso hacer el listo y dijo algo así como "Aterrizar no: *a-lu-ni-zar*" y a la gente le gustó porque aquello proporcionaba la oportunidad de hacerse el listo con otro.

Ahora en serio: en realidad es **innecesario**, de la misma manera que cuando un hidroavión se posa sobre un lago no es "alaguizar" ni si es en un pantano es "apantanizar". En inglés no hay confusión entre "Earth" y "land" y se dice "Moon landing" o "Loquesea landing" sin problema.

Así que, por favor, dejen de proponer términos enrevesados para complicarle la vida a los hispanohablantes. Gracias.

Comment: Completamente de acuerdo. Imposible decirlo más claro, con menos palabras.

Answer (score 2):

### Amercurizar

Parece que había algûn tipo de libro educativo utilizado por el Gimnasio Internacional de Medellín que usaba la palabra "amercurizar", aterrizar en el planeta Mercurio. Curiosamente solo puedo encontrar evidencia de su existencia en [dos páginas](https://www.gim.edu.co/2011/08/02/acta-12-leccion-de-la-experiencia/) [asociadas con la escuela](http://www.gim.edu.co/2011/08/23/110726-protocolo-leccion-de-la-experiencia/), asi que quizás era algo producido para el uso interno de la institución.

[La primera página](http://www.gim.edu.co/2011/08/23/110726-protocolo-leccion-de-la-experiencia/) nos dice que:

> A partir de la presentación por parte del centro infantil de la novela
> llamada «Todos a amercurizar»,  hubo un impacto muy positivo en los
> integrantes del Consejo de Maestros. Los comentarios acerca de su
> contenido fueron muestra de que en cierta manera se ha logrado
> comprender más sobre las experiencias significativas, ya que fue de
> una forma poco tediosa, con tacto, espontaneidad y finura a partir de
> un escenario que permitiò a los niños entrar en el juego de «Viajar
> por el espacio y los planetas».

Y la [otra](http://www.gim.edu.co/2011/08/23/110726-protocolo-leccion-de-la-experiencia/) dice que:

> Las Maestras Jardineras en voz de Nancy Monte,  presentaron el sexto
> capítulo de la novela llamado «Todos a Amercurizar» (ver adjunto).

Tambien la usa al menos un periodista, en [el Diario Sur](https://www.diariosur.es/opinion/hoyo-sombra-20180718001953-ntvo.html):

> En Mercurio, si alguien amercuriza -no caeré en la tentación de decir
> aterriza- se achicharra y un poco más allá de Marte se congela, si no
> antes.

Esta palabra obviamente se emplea en varios libros estilísticos como el que menciona la otra respuesta.

### Aplutonizar, Avenuzar

Pude encontrar una extraña [obra educativa](https://www.portaleducativo.net/biblioteca/GP4_comprension_Los_bordes_universo.pdf) que utiliza ambas palabras, así como "amartizar":

> **MAD**: ¡Yo no soy un niño! Sé manejar la nave, yo sé más que los científicos
> de cabeza cuadrada y más que muchos expertos, sé aplutonizar, sé
> amartizar, sé avenuzar.

Aunque este sitio web no sea famoso, utiliza estas palabras en una obra de ficción aparentemente con el fin de presentarlas como términos comunes en el futuro ficticio.

### Aplanetizar

Este término es uno de los mas generales. No digo que esta fuente sea precisamente confiable, pero ya es [un libro](https://books.google.com/books?id=vsXcE4a7-zwC&pg=PA710&lpg=PA710&dq=aplanetizar&source=bl&ots=tZL6xPBUbf&sig=ACfU3U2L1PznscBLBwxw30jo-QfdORpZQA&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiByL_qvOHjAhULlKwKHbwrAxoQ6AEwEnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=aplanetizar&f=false) e incluso se remonta a 1955 (supongo que en inglés).

> En cuanto dejaron de hablar los Altísimos, el bello mensaje de
> Lucifer, que en aquel entonces era el soberano del sistema de Satania,
> comenzó a aplanetizar.

[Una presentación de UNAM](https://www.irya.unam.mx/web/contenido/divulgacion/presentaciones/el%20cuete%20de%20enviar%20al%20espacio%20un%20cohete.pdf), una universidad mexicana, tambien la emplea.

Incluso [hay un ejemplo de 1957](http://www.ulpiano.org.ve/revistas/bases/artic/texto/RDUCV/13/rucv_1957_13_233-246.pdf):

> El lanzamiento de satélites artificiales y el establecimiento de
> estaciones supone el dominio del espacio interplanetario. Si se habla
> de un “Derecho astronáutico” , se circunscribiría la regulación
> jurídica a la máquina espacial en que se viaja. Cuando ésta se
> detiene, sea para tomar contacto con las estaciones instaladas en la
> órbita de la Tierra o más allá, o para “aplanetizar” —según la
> expresión de Laming— en la Luna o en un planeta, se habría de recurrir
> a normas que no encuadran dentro de lo “astronáutico”.

Se nota que este articulo hace referencia a otro ejemplo mas temprano del uso de este termino por parte de alguien que se llamaba Laming.

Al parecer en el pasado este verbo tenía [otro significado](https://books.google.com/books?id=aNg_AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA343&lpg=PA343&dq=Por%20mil%20pesetas%20se%20vende%20uno,%20en%20perfecto%20estado%20de%20conservaci%C3%B3n,%20cuyo%20objetivo,%20de%2095%20mil%C3%ADmetros%20de%20di%C3%A1metro,%20ha%20sido%20aplanetiza&source=bl&ots=Z_YmSXdIlo&sig=ACfU3U2gBunh3QrDsSmihCSY0GN_6STkLA&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiNnoyNwOHjAhUBS60KHffjCyUQ6AEwAHoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=Por%20mil%20pesetas%20se%20vende%20uno%2C%20en%20perfecto%20estado%20de%20conservaci%C3%B3n%2C%20cuyo%20objetivo%2C%20de%2095%20mil%C3%ADmetros%20de%20di%C3%A1metro%2C%20ha%20sido%20aplanetiza&f=false).

> ANTEOJO ASTRONÓMICO. Por mil pesetas se vende uno, en perfecto estado
> de conservación, cuyo objetivo, de 95 milímetros de diámetro, ha sido
> aplanetizado por M. Henry del observatorio de Paris.

Answer (score 0):

Sólo a título informativo, y aunque suene irónico, pero para que también sirva para incitar a la reflexión:

[image: Portada de un cómic de Tintín]